# A Fragmented Puzzle

Tags: word

Your roommate is on vacation, and you need to get something off his laptop. You ring him up, asking if you can borrow his computer.

"Sure, if you can get in," he replies.

"What? But it's your laptop!"

"Give me a break, man. You know how my memory is. Tell you what — look through the second drawer of the desk and you might find a clue."

You thank your friend, and begin rummaging through his stuff. You don't feel very nice doing so, of course, but it's getting late and you need those files. To your dismay, all you can find is the left half of a torn note:

```
   edi
   est
   ser
   ing
restau
    on
   myo
   mus
   hot
```

*Edit: Right-aligned the words to make it clearer that you have the **left** half of the note*

Knowing your friend's naïveté you figure that the password is probably just a single word, and start racking your brain for ideas.

**What is your friend's password?**

---

Hint:

> Each row can be extended to form words with a certain property. Some words are more obscure than others, but `restau` does not become `restaurant`/`restaurants`.

Comment: ;) if you just need the files and its a windows laptop all you need is a linux live USB drive

Comment: Without any hints, I could technically come up with so so so many words with these alphabets I guess that would leave this question as being too broad

Comment: @skv You could, but this isn't a cryptogram. Once you play around with the fragments for a bit a pattern should emerge.

Comment: It could be a message starting with >! edit
>! established
>! serv
>! ing
>! restaurant I am on the right path?

Comment: Trying to extend each row is on the right path, but pairing `ser` with `ing` is not.

Comment: @Sp3000 Just for a clarification, the left side means all the words start with those? For example, regarding **myo**, I need to find a word starting with myo or containing myo?

Comment: Is the relevant language necessarily English?

Comment: @randal'thor Yes, the relevant language is English

Comment: @Emi987 It's heavily implied but if you want confirmation then yes these are prefixes

Comment: Great puzzle, Sp3000! Solution very nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> FAVORITES
>  
>  
>  Each prefix can be extended by adding a letter, then an anagram of the prefix.
>  
>  `edi     F    ied
>  est     A    tes
>  ser     V    ers
>  ing     O    ing
>  restau  R    ateurs
>  on      I    on
>  myo     T    omy
>  mus     E    ums
>  hot     S    hot`

Comment: You enter `favorites` into your friend's laptop — success! In the end it turned out that there was no right half to the note — all the necessary letters were already on the left half!

Answer (score 3):

Is the password

> food

?

It seems too simple to me, but [you said](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/a-fragmented-puzzle#comment13910_4784) to look for a pattern and my guesses are:

> edi**ble**
> est??
> ser**ving**
> ing**redients**
> restau**rant**
> on**ion**
> m**a**yo**nnaise** (I'm guessing that's a typo?)
> mus**tard**
> hot **sauce**?

Comment: Nice observations, but unfortunately `myo` is not a typo :)

Comment: est would be estate.  Ate is related to food too :)